# How can I show the + register in Airline?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc, plugin-airline

I'm using the Airline plugin.

How can I show the `+` register in Airline ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(not using Airline, guessing from the documentation)

You can add the following to your status line and it will show the content of the register +:

```
set statusline+=%{@+}
```

Then you have different choice in airline (also guessing from the doc):

From `add_statusline_func`:

```
let w:airline_section_b = '%{@+}'
```

From `airline-sections`:

```
let g:airline_section_c = airline#section#create(['%{@+}'])
```

Comment: i have put the code in my vimrc and is not worked?

Comment: I think it's normal. As I said, I do not use airline, so this is just a guess about  how you can do. The main point is to use the `%{@+}` somewhere in the airline configuration. You just need to see at which point in your configuration it must be placed ;)

Comment: Thanks. its Wokrs.
 'let g:airline_section_b = '%{@+}''